# How is circular array stored in memory

Tags: c, arrays

I was going through the array implementation of circular queue from here-
http://www.programmingspark.in/2012/07/c-program-to-implement-circular-queue.html

In this circular array is used.My question is how is this array stored in memory?For normal array say int[4],4 memory locations are allocated each for an integer.These are contiguous locations.Here also in the case of circular,the locations allocated should be contiguous too.So how does it become circular?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Circular arrays are stored exactly like normal arrays in memory, because they *are* normal arrays.

It's just a matter of [using them differently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer#How_it_works) to make them circular.

Answer (score 1):

> So how does it become circular?

When circular queue is implemented using arrays then its memory representation is same as array except the logic/algorithm for addition and removal of elements changes.